# How can I put global template helpers together in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

I have several global template helpers

```
Template.registerHelper("termSuffix",function(){});

Template.registerHelper("subjects",function(){});

Template.registerHelper("date",function(){});
...
```

I tried this (like normal/local template helpers)

```
Template.registerHelper({
      termSuffix:function(){},
      subjects:function(){},
      date:function(){}
});
```

But it throws `Exception from Tracker recompute function:Error: No such function: termSuffix`

Comment: I don't believe it's possible.  Do you have a compelling reason for wanting to do this?  It would be nice(r) if it was consistent with the non global template helpers, but this syntax is not supported (at least as far as the docs are concerned)  https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper

Comment: I have too many `Template.registerHelper` in the application and it seems not too tidy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is not supported for global helpers.  [Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper) [Code](https://github.com/meteor/blaze/blob/6c498c6b649f64c5d15c6ee505573ec391a2c8b1/packages/blaze/lookup.js#L6)

If you think it's a compelling enough change to the library, you could submit a pull request.

Meanwhile, you can wrap the Template.registerHelper function with your own:

```
function registerGlobalHelpers(helpers){
    _.chain(helpers)
     .each( (fn, name) => { Template.registerHelper(name, fn); })
     .value();
  }
```

or defined without [chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) in underscorejs:

```
function registerGlobalHelpers(helpers){
  _.each(helpers, (fn, name) => { Template.registerHelper(name, fn); });
  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
registerGlobalHelpers({
      termSuffix:function(){},
      subjects:function(){},
      date:function(){}
})
```

Comment: Clean, short and elegant. Thanks @JeremyK +1

Comment: Most of those commands are excessive, you could just use `_.each(helpers, (fn, name) => { Template.registerHelper(name, fn); });` and that would be enough.

Comment: @Styx,  yes, `.key()` can and should be removed alowing the iteratee function to be simplified - I'll update this.  The rest is a matter of preference.  I like the the fluent interface approach of chaining commands, so generally use .chain / .value with underscore.  Admittedly, when there is only one remaining commend between them, it's debateable if the add much value!  I'll add both options to the answer